# WSO2 Identity Server - multiple users under an admin group

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We would like to have a single WSO2 Identity Server (4.5.0) serve many different applications.

However, we cannot give the admin password (listed in user-mgt.xml) to all these dev teams.
But these dev teams will need to write software that will be calling the PDP/PIP WSO2 APIs.

So, we must have separate accounts for each dev team. We want these LDAP accounts in a single 'admin' LDAP group. And we want them to connect and execute these WSO2 APIs with these accounts.

Is that possible? Let me know if that does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You can configure different roles with different permission levels and assign each user to each of these roles. Following document will help you.

[1] - http://docs.wso2.com/display/IS450/Configuring+Roles

Thanks,
Pushpalanka